# Isolation Forest in R

Tags: r, outliers, anomaly-detection, r-forge

I'm currently working on identifying outliers in my data set using the IsolationForest method in R. The execution of the existing project on https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=479 failed, it displays:

```
RTver <- read.dcf(file=system.file("DESCRIPTION", package=pkgname), fields="Version") 
Error in system.file("DESCRIPTION", package = pkgname) : object 'pkgname' not found
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: can we please all agree that Forest of Solitude is a superior name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified `package`; `pkgname` is just a placeholder.

Not sure why you want to extract the version number from the Debian Control File (DCF), but for package `IsolationForest` the command would be (provided you have installed `IsolationForest`)

```
RTver <- read.dcf(
    file = system.file("DESCRIPTION", package = "IsolationForest"), 
    fields = "Version");
RTver;
#     Version
#[1,] "0.0-26"
```

Comment: but for package IsolationForest the command would be (provided you have installed IsolationForest)

The problem is that i didn't know how to install the IsolationForest package. In fact, this is the first time i use R and i find many problems. I would be so grateful if you told me how to install it?

Comment: It seems that `IsolationForest` is currently not part of CRAN; to install from source you can do `install.packages("http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/IsolationForest_0.0-26.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")`.

Comment: What didn't work? I don't see any errors. You need to be specific.